# Why my async function doesn't await to the Promise in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, async-await, promise

My code is the following:

```
const match = async (tender, searchCriteria) => {

  const tenderAccount = await tenderAccountController.findOrCreate(
    tender,
    searchCriteria,
  );

  if (searchCriteria.emailFrequency !== 'real-time') {
    return null;
  }

  // Notify Stakeholders
  await notifyStakeholders(tender, tenderAccount, searchCriteria);
};
```

This function "match" is called inside a for loop [for (const searchCriteria of searchCriterias) {}]

findOrCreate function is the following:

```
exports.findOrCreate = async (tender, searchCriteria) => {
    console.log("Search Criteria Name: " + searchCriteria.name)
    console.log("Tender Name: " + tender.name)

    // Check if it already exists
    let doc = await TenderAccount.findOne({
        tender: tender._id,
        account: searchCriteria.account._id
    })

    console.log("Doc: " + doc)
  
    if(doc) {
        // If it exists, update searchCriterias
        await TenderAccount.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $addToSet: { searchCriterias: searchCriteria } })

        return doc;
    } else {
        doc = await TenderAccount.create({
            tender,
            account: searchCriteria.account,
            searchCriterias: [searchCriteria],
            dueDate: tender.submissionDeadlineDate
        })

        return doc;
    }
};
```

My problem is that it doesn't await to findOne query. It just complete all the inital loop (searchcriteria loop) and when loop ended it returns the query result.
In my console I got this:

```
Search Criteria Name: test-sc
Tender Name: test-tender
Search Criteria Name: test2-sc
Tender Name: test2-tender
Search Criteria Name: test3-sc
Tender Name: test3-tender
Doc: null
Doc: null
Doc: null
```

And I don't understand it, it supose to console.log the doc after the tender name console.log right?

I will appreciate your answers.

Comment: You've not added the `for` loop where you call `match`. Also, it's not logging the doc, it's logging `tender.name` (again) (which mysteriously changes from having a value before the call to `findOne()` to being `null` after it?)

Comment: "it supose to console.log the doc after the tender name console.log right?" yes, and it does. But since you have `await` between those console.log calls, something else can kick in, like another `findOrCreate()` call. The problem is how you call all of that. It looks like you make those calls concurrently, instead of sequenatially. Where's your loop? The problem lies within it.

Comment: "*This function "match" is called inside a for loop*" - please post that code, as that appears to be where the mistake is. Did you `await` the calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call an `async` function without calling `await`, it will continue execution without waiting for the promise to be resolved. So if your for loop looks like: `for (...) match(...)` instead of `for (...) await match(...)`, it will execute all matches immedietly one after the other hence why the `Search Criteria Name` and `Tender Name` all get printed first in a row.

Adding `await` to the `match` call should give the result you were expecting.

Comment: Yes, I added await to the match call but I get the same result. But I'm working in Visual Studio Code and if I put my cursor over await, it says "'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.". So I only get this message in this await, do you know why?

Comment: Oh I found my mystake i had a function inside a function where I called match sho that's why await didn't affect. Thanks!!!